# How to prevent slash expansion in NPM custom arguments?

Tags: npm, git-bash

In package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    ...
```

In my Bash script:

```
npm run build -- --base-href "/mydir/"
```

When running the Bash script, this happens:

```
ng build --prod "--base-href" "C:/Program Files/Git/mydir/"
```

But I want:

```
ng build --prod "--base-href" "/mydir/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the suggestion of [Tolga Balci (`tolgabalci`)](https://github.com/tolgabalci) in [angular/angular-cli issue 5606](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5606#issuecomment-393357278):

> See "[MinGW Posix path conversion](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion)" for when conversions occur:
>
> You can tell git bash to avoid the conversion for the `-bh` parameter by setting the `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL` environment variable while calling `ng` like this:
>
> ```
> MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL="-bh=" ng build --prod -bh="/en/"
> ```
>
> Note that to use the exclusion you must use `-bh` parameter with an `=`, not space, since `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL` will think the value after the space is a different parameter.

The OP [Marco Eckstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/443836/marco-eckstein) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662064/how-to-prevent-slash-expansion-in-npm-custom-arguments/50663405?noredirect=1#comment88345990_50663405):

> In my case, it is (all on the same line):
>
> ```
> MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL="--base-href" npm run build -- --base-href="/mydir/"
> ```

Comment: Thanks. So in my case, it is: MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL="--base-href" npm run build -- --base-href="/mydir/" (all on the same line)

Comment: @MarcoEckstein OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.